# Specflow StepArgumentTransformation: move to separate file

Tags: specflow

I am trying to place my `StepArgumentTransformations` into a "Utility File" so that multiple StepDefinitions can use them.
Unfortunately it looks like they need to be in the same StepDefinition class where they are used.

Is there a way so that specflow searches them in the whole project? (like it does for the step bindings)
I don't want to copy the transformations into each StepDefinition class where I want to use them.

Comment: Not sure why the down votes.  It is a valid question and the answer happened to be my exact same solution to the exact same problem.  (Just because one answers themselves doesn't mean its not valid)

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.

I forgot to place the [Binding] attribute on the "Utility class" where i moved my StepArgumentTransformation to.